# Unable to create javax script engine for groovy even when -lib flag is used in ant

Tags: java, groovy, ant

I am using groovy script in build.xml file and have given -lib option when running ant from command line.

**ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib -DtestBool=true -d**

The lib dir has groovy-all jar and bsf.jar. When I check the verbose output, I dont see the Jar being loaded and the build failed with below error.

**Unable to create javax script engine for groovy**

My ant version is 1.9.2. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I use classpath attribute in script ant task for example

`<script language="groovy" src = "${build.scripts}/my-script.groovy" classpath="${build.script.classpath}"/>`

where classpath is list of required JAR files. In my case this list are:

```
build.script.classpath=${build.lib}/groovy-2.5.2.jar;${build.lib}/groovy-jsr223-2.5.2.jar;
```

I think it will help